# Someone using my image as his profile picture on Instagram

Tags: facebook, instagram, profile-picture

I don't have an Instagram account and there is someone using my picture as his profile picture without using my name, how can I stopping that one from doing that?

I didn't publish this image before over internet, may be he got it from an stolen device or something like that.

Please any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have an Instagram account, please [fill out this form](https://help.instagram.com/contact/636276399721841).

From [Instagram Help Center](https://help.instagram.com/370054663112398):

> Instagram takes safety seriously. If someone created an Instagram account pretending to be you, you can report it to us. Make sure to provide all the requested info, including a photo of your government-issued ID.
>
> If you have an Instagram account, you can report it to us from within the app, or [by filling out this form](https://help.instagram.com/contact/636276399721841). If you don't have an Instagram account, please [fill out this form](https://help.instagram.com/contact/636276399721841).
>
> We only respond to reports sent to us from the person who's being impersonated or a representative of the person who's being impersonated (example: a parent). If someone you know is being impersonated, please encourage that person to report it.
>
> Keep in mind that your report is anonymous, except if you’re reporting an intellectual property infringement. The account you reported won’t see who reported them.
>
> Note: If you're having trouble uploading a photo of your ID from a mobile phone, please try [submitting this form](https://help.instagram.com/contact/636276399721841) from a computer.

Comment: I already filed it, but I didn't get response

Comment: Getting response or not is depend on Facebook. We are here just to provide help.

Comment: Yes I know you are just to help, So I asked to know if there is any way else to get what I need.
Thanks